# How to write the tab character into the InputQuery?

Tags: delphi

I need to allow the user to write the tab character (`#9`) into the editor of the `InputQuery` function.
Pressing the tab key moves the focus on the Ok button and pressing `Alt + 0 0 9` have no effect.

The only way I've found is copying the tab from a text editor (like Notepad) and pasteing it to the `InputQuery` editor but it's very uncomforable for everyone...

Does someone know other ways?

Comment: You need to abandon the `InputQuery` function to do this. Which is a pretty good idea in any case, because the function's GUI looks like a relic from the 90s. A modern alternative should look more like [this](https://english.rejbrand.se/rejbrand/article.asp?ItemIndex=356).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand  Your TMultiInputBox looks really nice. You published the whole source code, but I see no mention of any license to use it. Can it be used freely?

Comment: @MatthiasB: Sure, just make sure not to remove the banner at the top of the unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [AmigoJack's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4299358/amigojack) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66252162/282848) is correct, I would suggest a different approach.

Personally, I want the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to work as usual in dialog boxes. I expect it to move focus to the next control.

So my suggestion would be to introduce a different hotkey, preferably <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, to insert a `#9` at the caret location (replacing any selection).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> for `#9` is somewhat [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation), since I is the 9th letter in the English alphabet. (A different common hotkey is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> but this causes a conflict if you use page controls or some other form of tabs. I prefer <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.)

Obviously, this should be a local hotkey for the edit box, so that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> is not stolen from other controls when the edit box doesn't have focus. Use the edit box's `OnKeyPress` handler:

```pascal
procedure TMyInputDialog.InputEditKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Sender is TEdit then
    case Key of
      ^I:
        begin
          TEdit(Sender).SelText := #9;
          Key := #0;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

The `Key := #0` statement is needed to suppress the invalid input beep. (Because now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> is a *valid* input.)

Comment: Also: `I` for "_indent_".

Answer (score 1):

That "editor" is just a `TEdit`. All you have to achieve is manage to enter a tab character into a `TEdit` the way you want it (which also doesn't work by default). If you don't find a way to do that then you won't have any luck with `InputQuery()` either.

However, a `TMemo` has this already on board with its `.WantTabs` property. But then again this is a multiline input control - you have to decide yourself if that's an alternative for you.

The code to reproduce `InputQuery()` is rather trivial - it's just creating a form and the controls on the fly and frees them all after a button is clicked. You could also use the designer to create that form. Or modify *Andreas*' code to display a `TMemo` instead of a `TEdit`.

Comment: And probably you can even have a Win32 single-line edit control that handles tab characters. You just need to alter the `WM_GETDLGCODE` processing, no?